# Select separado por ponto e vírgula para xls

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, csv

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
var cmd = @"SELECT
                  mt.Id + ';' + mt.Nome + ';' + mt.Cidade AS Resultado
            FROM MinhaTable mt";

var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
                    var result = objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>(cmd).ToList<string>();

                    FileStreamResult fileStreamResult = null;

                    using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using(var csvWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                        {
                            foreach (var line in result)
                            {
                                csvWriter.WriteLine(line);
                            }
                            csvWriter.Flush();
                        }
                        fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray()), "text/plain");
                    }

                    if (fileStreamResult == null)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Não foi possível gerar o arquivo!");
                    }

                    var grid = new GridView();
                    grid.DataSource = fileStreamResult;
                    grid.DataBind();

                    Response.ClearContent();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + provaOnline.Descricao + "-" + provaOnline.DataLiberacaoInicial.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH-mm") + ".xls");
                    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

                    Response.Charset = "";
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

                    grid.RenderControl(htw);

                    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();

                    return View("PrintRelExcel");
```

Como podem ver, meu select retorna uma `List<string>` com valores separados por ponto e vírgula:

```
[1] "1;José;São Paulo"
[2] "2;Maria;São Paulo"
```

O objetivo é transforma-los em um **Excel** da seguinte forma:

```
     A      B          C
  +----+--------+-----------+
1 | 1  | José   | São Paulo |
2 | 2  | Maria  | São Paulo |
  +----+--------+-----------+
```

Mas na linha em que uso:

```
grid.DataSource = fileStreamResult;
```

Um erro é gerado:

> O tipo da fonte de dados é inválido. Ele deve ser um IListSource,
>   IEnumerable ou IDataSource.

Isso acontece, pois como a própria `Exception` já diz, `DataSource` só pode receber os tipos citados, e `fileStreamResult` não se engloba.

Existe alguma outra alternativa para gerar meu **.xls** ??

Comment: Qual seu problema? Não sabe gravar em um arquivo? Não sabe criar a *view*? para retornar isto? Explique melhor qual é a real dúvida. O SQL está correto. Talvez possa melhorar para evitar certas surpresas dependendo do dado.

Comment: Editado. Expliquei melhor... Preciso saber como fica o controller e a view que receberá o arquivo para fazer download instantâneo.

Comment: Ainda não consegui entender exatamente o que é a pergunta, qual é a dificuldade que está tendo. Já tem uma resposta e votada. EU achei uma solução bem ruim e nem sei se faz o que você quer, mas você pode dizer se te ajuda. Eu não iria por este caminho. É uma solução complicado e não usa a *view*, não é algo sobre MVC como você pede. Não sei porque votaram nisto.

Comment: [A melhor solução que eu conheço é esta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6989909/1314276), que não necessariamente usa o resultado de um SQL, mas sim uma lista qualquer. Se quiser, adapto como resposta.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez você sempre me salva, rsrsrs... Você faria esse enorme favor em me ajudar realizando a adaptação como resposta?

Comment: Só preciso saber como você dispara o select na base e como ele retorna, aí monto a resposta pra você.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o objetivo é gerar um XLS ou XLSX, isso que você está tentando não faz sentido. O correto é [usar um pacote NuGet que auxilia você a gerar um Excel](http://epplus.codeplex.com/):

```
PM> Install-Package EPPlus
```

Montei um *Helper* que faz essa exportação:

```
using MeuProjeto.Common.Ferramentas;
using MeuProjeto.Common.Models;
using MeuProjeto.Models;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MeuProjeto.Helpers
{
    public static class ExcelHelper
    {
        public static byte[] ExportarListaParaExcel<T>(IEnumerable<T> lista, String tituloPlanilha = "Exportação para Excel")
            where T: class, IEntidade, new()
        {
            using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Eu mesmo";
                excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Title = tituloPlanilha;
                var sheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(tituloPlanilha);
                sheet.Name = tituloPlanilha;

                var properties = ReflectionUtils.ExtrairPropertiesDeObjeto(new T()).Where(p => !p.Name.EndsWith("Id")).ToList();
                var titulos = properties.Select(p => p.AtributoDisplayName() != null ? p.AtributoDisplayName().DisplayName : p.Name).ToArray();
                var i = 1;
                foreach (var titulo in titulos)
                {
                    sheet.Cells[1, i++].Value = titulo;
                }

                var rowIndex = 2;
                foreach (var item in lista)
                {
                    var col = 1;
                    foreach (var prop in properties.Where(p => !p.Name.EndsWith("Id")))
                    {
                        var val = item.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(item, null);
                        String str;

                        if (val == null)
                        {
                            str = "";
                        }
                        else if (val.GetType().IsPrimitive || val.GetType() == typeof(Decimal) || val.GetType() == typeof(String) || val.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
                        {
                            str = val.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            str = val.GetType().GetProperty("Nome").GetValue(val, null).ToString();
                        }
                        sheet.Cells[rowIndex, col++].Value = str ?? "";
                    }

                    rowIndex++;
                }

                return excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();
            }
        }

        public static byte[] ExportarViewModelParaExcel(object viewModel, String tituloPlanilha = "Exportação para Excel")
        {
            using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Eu mesmo";
                excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Title = tituloPlanilha;

                foreach (var objeto in ReflectionUtils.ExtrairPropertiesDeObjeto(viewModel).ToList())
                {
                    var sheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(objeto.Name);
                    sheet.Name = objeto.Name;

                    if (objeto.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)))
                    {
                        // É uma lista
                        var lista = (IEnumerable)objeto.GetValue(viewModel, null);
                        if (lista == null) continue;
                        var fields = lista.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                        var titulos = fields.Select(p => p.AtributoDisplayName() != null ? p.AtributoDisplayName().DisplayName : p.Name).ToArray();
                        var i = 1;
                        foreach (var titulo in titulos)
                        {
                            sheet.Cells[1, i++].Value = titulo;
                        }

                        var rowIndex = 2;
                        foreach (var item in lista)
                        {
                            var col = 1;
                            foreach (var field in fields)
                            {
                                var val = item.GetType().GetField(field.Name).GetValue(item);
                                String str;

                                if (val == null)
                                {
                                    str = "";
                                }
                                else if (val.GetType().IsPrimitive || val.GetType() == typeof(Decimal) || val.GetType() == typeof(String) || val.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
                                {
                                    str = val.ToString();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    str = val.GetType().GetField("Nome").GetValue(val).ToString();
                                }
                                sheet.Cells[rowIndex, col++].Value = str ?? "";
                            }

                            rowIndex++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // É um objeto
                        var obj = objeto.GetValue(viewModel, null);
                        var fields = obj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                        var titulos = fields.Select(p => new {
                            Titulo = p.AtributoDisplayName() != null ? p.AtributoDisplayName().DisplayName : p.Name, 
                            Valor = p.GetValue(obj)
                        }).ToList();

                        var i = 1;
                        foreach (var titulo in titulos)
                        {
                            sheet.Cells[i, 1].Value = titulo.Titulo;
                            sheet.Cells[i++, 2].Value = titulo.Valor;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Também é preciso adicionar esta classe estática aqui em algum lugar do seu projeto:

```
public static class ReflectionUtils 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objeto"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> ExtrairPropertiesDeObjeto(Object objeto)
    {
        return objeto.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public |
                               BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="property"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DisplayNameAttribute ExtrairAtributoDisplayNameDeProperty(PropertyInfo property) 
    {
        var atributo = (DisplayNameAttribute)property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
        return atributo;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="field"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DisplayNameAttribute ExtrairAtributoDisplayNameDeField(FieldInfo field)
    {
        var atributo = (DisplayNameAttribute)field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
        return atributo;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="property"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DisplayNameAttribute AtributoDisplayName(this PropertyInfo property)
    {
        return ExtrairAtributoDisplayNameDeProperty(property);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="field"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DisplayNameAttribute AtributoDisplayName(this FieldInfo field)
    {
        return ExtrairAtributoDisplayNameDeField(field);
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
public ActionResult ExportarParaExcel() 
{
    var lista = /* Faça a sua seleção aqui */
    return File(ExcelHelper.ExportarListaParaExcel<MeuModel>(lista), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "teste.xlsx");
}
```

Comment: Pergunta editada, acho que ficou mais claro agora...

Comment: Ah, você quer popular uma Grid. Bom, simplesmente está tudo errado nesse código. Dá pra jogar tudo fora e fazer de novo. DataGrid aceita `List<Entidade>`. Veja: você primeiro usa o Entity Framework errado, depois você passa pra um CSV sem necessidade, e ainda depois você passa o CSV para a Grid. Jogue tudo fora e faça outro código. Vai ficar melhor.

Comment: Sobre o select eu preciso mesmo que ele seja daquela forma! Então como eu poderia passar os dados para a Grid? Estou iniciando nisso ainda...

Comment: Já te disse. Com uma `List<Entidade>`. `Entidade` é o *Model* em questão.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve então realizar a consulta seguindo os padrões do SQL, e então baseado no resultado da sua consulta formatar para csv ou outro formado desejado.

Pesquisando achei até exemplos:
[Exportar Dados do SQL Server para CSV (em inglês)](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-data-from-SQL-Server-to-CSV-file-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public partial class CS : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void ExportCSV(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constr =     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM     Customers"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);

                        //Build the CSV file data as a Comma separated     string.
                        string csv = string.Empty;

                        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            //Add the Header row for CSV file.
                            csv += column.ColumnName + ',';
                        }

                        //Add new line.
                        csv += "\r\n";

                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                            {
                                //Add the Data rows.
                                csv +=     row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',';
                            }

                            //Add new line.
                            csv += "\r\n";
                        }

                        //Download the CSV file.
                        Response.Clear();
                        Response.Buffer = true;
                        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",     "attachment;filename=SqlExport.csv");
                        Response.Charset = "";
                        Response.ContentType = "application/text";
                        Response.Output.Write(csv);
                        Response.Flush();
                        Response.End();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

E na página:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CS.aspx.cs" Inherits="CS" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button Text="Export" OnClick="ExportCSV" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Shura16 , mas falei sobre csv pois ele consegue trabalhar com a questão do ponto e vírgula, e consigo abri-lo no Excel. Mas o objetivo verdadeiro é gerar um .xls com o select mostrado na pergunta.

Comment: Pergunta editada, acho que ficou mais claro agora...